# ATS Disabled, Still Cannot Access API Running on Same Machine as Simulator

Tags: ios9, xcode7, nsurl, osx-elcapitan

My app attempts to access an API I am serving from my mac like so:

```
http://10.12.38.207:7005/api/v0/userfiles/
```

I have already disabled ATS in my info.plist (I know this is unsafe and I will add a specific exception rather than entirely disabling ATS once I figure out this problem). On a real device everything works fine, I am also able to curl the API from my terminal and receive the appropriate response. Why is this causing an exception in iOS9 simulators even though ATS is disabled? I appreciate any help as I am unable to run any UI tests (The API mocks a device that my app communicates with to display its filesystem.) It is also worth mentioning that I AM able to access the real device's API, just not the local API that I am serving from my mac (The two should be identical from the apps point of view). I cannot use 127.0.0.1:7005 or localhost:7005 because part of the test involves connecting to the device via its IP over the network that both the iOS device and client device are connected to. 
[Screenshot of the exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zY74e.png)

Comment: An interesting note. I am able to access the API only when I reference it through `http://127.0.0.1:7005/api/v0/userfiles` but like I said I don't want to use this method. I know it isn't due to a problem with the network as I am able to access the API in the manner I originally posted when I am using an iOS 8.4 simulator. Other SO articles I have been reading seem to elude to the fact that this is a bug that apple must fix for iOS9/El Capitan...?

Comment: Just to clarify, `http://localhost:7005/api/v0/userfiles` and `http://0.0.0.0:7005/api/v0/userfiles` also work. but this is probably irrelevant.